# spring: hook between data binding and validation

Tags: spring, validation, data-binding, spring-security, spring-roo

I have a Roo generated application and use validation, spring security with a custom PermissionEvaluator and the generated web controllers. My entity has a field like this:

```
@NotNull
private Date creationDate;
```

This field is set automatically inside the controller's create method when saving the entity and is not included in the form (render="false").

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#myEntity, 'create')")
public String create(@Valid MyEntity myEntity,
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel,
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    // ... check binding result
    myEntity.setCreationDate(new Date());
    myEntity.persist();
    // ...
}
```

The problem is, that validation always fails because it runs before the field is set. The PermissionEvaluator (called by @PreAuthorize) is also missing the value. How can I place my code somewhere between data binding and validation so that the entity is complete right from the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the problem of `@PreAutorize` move the persistence logic to a `@Service` bean and call it from the controller. This way security check will be after validation. Roo can help you on it with [service command](http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/base-layers.html#service-layer).

Second, you can use *validation groups* to make different validation on for the same entity. [This](http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/jsr_303_beans_validation_using) and [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/08/validation-groups-in-spring-mvc.html) are two howto post.

An example:

```
@RequestMapping("/myEntity")
public MyEntityController {
   @Autowired
   MyEntityService myEntityService;

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/html")     
   public String create(@Validated({Account.ValidationStepOne.class}) MyEntity myEntity,
        BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel,
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

       // ... check binding result
       myEntityService.save(myEntity);    
       //...
    }
}

@Service
public MyEntityService {

   @PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#myEntity, 'create')")
   public save(MyEntity myEntity) {
      //...
      myEntity.setCreationDate(new Date());
      myEntity.persist();          
   }
}
```

Good luck!